# jquery .fadeOut() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on swapping out some content in a simple div using the code below.

```
var slides = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
];
slides[0]['title'] = "Content One";
slides[0]['body'] = "Here is a little bit of useful information for you to read.";
slides[0]['link-text'] = "READ MORE...";
slides[0]['URL'] = "/go/somewhere";
slides[1]['title'] = "Content Two";
slides[1]['body'] = "This is different information for you to read.";
slides[1]['link-text'] = "READ THIS INSTEAD...";
slides[1]['URL'] = "/go/elsewhere";

var overlayTitle;
var overlayBody;
var overlayLink;
var i = 0;

var overlayInterval = setInterval(overlaySlider(), 600);

function overlaySlider() {
  if (i == 1) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }

  overlayTitle = slides[i]['title'];
  overlayBody = slides[i]['body'];
  overlayLink = '<a href="' + slides[i]['URL'] + '">' + slides[i]['link-text'] + '</a>';

  $("#hvoTitle").fadeOut()(400, function() {
    $(this).html(overlayTitle).fadeIn();
  });
  $("#hvoBody").fadeOut()(400, function() {
    $(this).html(overlayBody).fadeIn();
  });
  $("#hvoLink").fadeOut()(400, function() {
    $(this).html(overlayLink).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

Everything works until I get to the first .fadeOut, then I get an error that .fadeOut is not a function. I believe it should be in the version of the library I am using. (full, not slim).

Here is a fiddle I am trying to get working:

https://jsfiddle.net/529to1w5/41/

Comment: Problem ---> `fadeOut()(` Solution: `fadeout(`

Comment: @RandyCasburn gah! you're right!. If you post that as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

```
fadeOut()(
```

**Solution**

```
fadeout(
```

Simple syntax error, glad to help.